# Como ignoro los archivos de una carpeta en git.ignore

Tags: git, github, gitignore

tengo una carpeta con imagenes en VS en el git.ignore estoy ignorando de esta manera pero se me ignora la carpeta como ignoro todo el contenido dentro de la carpeta , pero no la carpeta?

api/Resources/Images/*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No estoy seguro de si hay alguna manera de hacer que git acepte carpetas vacías, que es lo que intentas hacer tú aquí... Al menos hasta donde yo he visto no se puede.

Dicho eso, hay una solución fácil: remueve esta línea de tu .gitignore: `api/Resources/Images/*` y ***CREA un nuevo `.gitignore` dentro de esa carpeta*** con el siguiente contenido:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Es decir, en la primera línea le pides que ignore ***TODO*** el contenido de la carpeta y en la segunda línea hacemos una excepción para el propio `.gitignore`, puesto que sin ella sería ignorado también! Con esto tendrás una carpeta que, *técnicamente*, está vacía.

Comment: muchas gracias !! de esa manera pude solucionar exactamente lo que quería !!!

Comment: La explicación es sencilla: git no hace tracking de "directorios/carpetas". Git hace tracking de *archivos*. Si un directorio no tiene archivos, git no lo guarda en una revisión. El truco que están haciendo aquí es justamente crear un archivo al que le van a hacer tracking dentro del directorio (el .gitignore) y de esta forma ya el directorio lo vas a tener... y _vacío_ (solo con el gitignore) si el .gitignore dice que ignores todo el directorio. Otra forma de hacerlo es mantener el .gitignore en la raiz y colocar un archivo como un readme dentro del directorio.